# R set working directory to folder

Tags: r

I am trying to set the working directory to a different subfolder in a function. I expected the print command to print

```
C:/Users/Blah/Desktop/dir2/SUBFOLDER
```

instead it prints

```
C:/Users/Blah/Desktop/dir2
```

Yet when I run dirs in console I get:

```
C:/Users/Blah/Desktop/dir2/SUBFOLDER 
...(Much longer list)
```

like I expected. Here is my code:

```
temp<-function(path)
{
  print(path) #output is C:/Users/Blah/Desktop/dir2
  setwd(path)
  print(getwd())
  xml=xmlParse("filename.xml")
  ...
}

dirs<-list.dirs("C:/Users/Blah/Desktop/dir2")
lapply(dirs,temp)#apply function tempt to every item in dirs
```

Comment: I guess the first directory is the root directory you specified. What about `lapply(dirs[-1],temp)`?

Comment: I don't know exactly what you see as output, but the first element of the vector (after running `dirs<-list.dirs("C:/Users/Blah/Desktop/dir2"`) is the current directory i.e. in your case `"C:/Users/Blah/Desktop/dir2"`. So, this is the one that would be printed first by your function (and then all the subfolders). At least this is the normal behaviour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you checked the optional arguments of list.dirs() ? (https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/list.files.html)

The documentation says that by default, the answer includes "path" itself, so your function temp will first be applied with the directory you give to list.dirs(), "C:/Users/Blah/Desktop/dir2".
You may want to try with list.dirs("C:/Users/Blah/Desktop/dir2", recursive = FALSE) (if it's ok with what you want)

Answer (score 0):

Your question is rather difficult to follow.

`list.dirs` will return (by default) the paths relative to the current working directory.

If you change the working directory, then the relative paths will not be valid.

You could try using `full.names = TRUE` within list.dirs having your `temp` function return the working directory to it's original state

```
temp <- function(path) {
           owd <- getwd()
           on.exit(setwd(owd))
           print(path) 
           setwd(path)
         print(getwd())
    }
```

An even better idea might be to, instead of messing with the working directory, simply pass the appropriate file name to `xmlParse` (or whatever your function is doing)

```
files <- list.files(pattern = '\\.xml$', recurvise = TRUE)
XML <-   lapply(files, xmlParse)
```

Comment: In my final code I did as you suggested (rather then changing setwd()) but @davidrd's solution was what I needed. Thanks!