# locating directory where R code is stored

Tags: r

I want to find the directory where my R code file is located. If I attempt to

```
source("dir/hh.R")
```

then I would need to know in advance the directory in which the script is located. I would like to automatically identify the directory of my script, so I can call it like this:

```
pathToMyScript <- findDirectoryOfMyScript("hh.R")
source(paste0(pathToMyScript, "/hh.r"))
```

What function can I used to find automatically the path of my R code? What would be `findDirectoryOfMyScript` like?

Comment: Not clear what you're asking. Possibly a duplicate of [Get the path of current script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47044068/get-the-path-of-current-script/47045368) ?

Comment: this link has dependency of Rstudio. It is working in Rstudio. was looking one that would work in R console.

Comment: There are solutions other than for RStudio at that link, if you scroll down.

Comment: saw that. none other than green tick seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

If you happen to know the name of the script **but not the directory it's stored in**, you can source it like this:

```
source(list.files(pattern = "nameOfFile.R", recursive = TRUE))
```

Notice that you can actually set a real pattern instead of the actual filename, like I used in the example.

Please be aware that if there are more than one file returned by the search done by `list.files`, `source` will return an error.

Comment: mm = source(list.files(pattern = "dv.R", recursive = TRUE))
Error in if (file == "") { : argument is of length zero

Comment: are you sure there is a file called `dv.R` in you tree? It **is case sensitive**

Comment: how to find tree?

Comment: You don't need to specify a path as the default one for `list.files` is `"."`. The error you're getting is because you don't have a file named `dv.R`

Comment: > rstudioapi::getSourceEditorContext()$path
[1] "C:/Users/kk/hh/dv.R"

Comment: i have filename dv.R.