# How to find the name of script that is currently running in R?

Tags: r, filenames, self-extracting

I have been trying to get the script name of an R script in R console. For example, I have the name of the R script “example.R”. I want to have this name as an assigned variable. I would like to do this without using `basename()` because I would like to define the working directory with the help of the name of the script as a variable.

I tried `scriptName` package and `current_filename()` function but it somehow gives me NULL. I expected to have the script name but I couldn’t have it. Does anyone have any idea how to do this?

Comment: Are you calling the script using `source()` or running it interactively?

Comment: @SamR I am running it interactively

Comment: Then it's impossible to figure that out, as "running interactively" means you're literally copy-pasting code to the console. R has no way of knowing from which script you copy-pasted that.

Comment: Are you using RStudio? If yes, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/47045368/1412059

Comment: Thanks @Roland. I have the answer there. I didn’t check it properly.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is provided in @Roland’s link. However, to make it specific, the code is ‘rstudioapi::getSourceEditorContext()$path’ which will provide the path of the script. After that, ‘basename’ could be used to extract the script name. All of these operations are done interactively, rather than using ‘source()’ in RStudio.